# How to use Eclipse Debug feature to get the entry and exit point of code flow

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, debugging

I have a large **Java** code base written with **Spring Boot**. I'm finding difficult to 
understand the code flow, like which line of what file is executed, and the rest sequence. 
But there doesnt seem any way with debug in eclipse as we need to explicitly define
break-points. 
Of course the `main` method in `ApplicationStartup.java` runs first, but after that, i do not know where it goes, while trying to debug with 'step into' or 'next line'

Importantly, I want to know which class or code is executed first when I hit api call from Postman.